# No such property: appCtx for class: groovy.lang.Binding - Cucumber, Grails

Tags: grails, cucumber

I'm using Grails 2.3.3 and Cucumber 0.10.0 and I'm trying to create an updated version of this example created by the author of the plugin: https://github.com/hauner/grails-cucumber/wiki/Testing-Grails-with-Cucumber-and-Geb 

The problem that I'm having is that with the new Grails the appCtx is no longer bound and cucumber needs it. The author comments on it in his github: 


*"Problem with appCtx is, that it is no longer in the binding of grails 2.3. You can probably work around it using Holders.applicationContext or setting appCtx with Holders.applicationContext. That's what the plugins 2.3 release will do to add compatibility with my older examples."*

I have changed the CucumberTestType.groovy to look like the one that he has on the newest branch-version.

```
private Binding createBinding () {
    Map variables = buildBinding.variables.clone () as Map
    variables.remove ("metaClass")
    variables.remove ("getMetaClass")
    variables.remove ("setMetaClass")
    setAppCtx (variables)
    setFunctionalTestBaseUrl (variables)
    new Binding (variables)
}

private void setAppCtx (Map variables) {
    // appCtx is no longer available in the (test-app) binding since grails 2.3

    // for plugin backward compatibility we add it if possible, i.e. not forked!
    if (!forked && !variables.containsKey('appCtx')) {
        variables.put('appCtx', getApplicationContext())
    }
}
```

But even after this, I still get the same error:
       `Error executing script TestApp: cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: appCtx for class: groovy.lang.Binding (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)`

Did I misunderstand what the author meant and therefore missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I published a 0.11.0-SNAPSHOT version of the plugin containing the grails 2.3 support.

I have also updated the examples projects (https://github.com/hauner/grails-cucumber/tree/master/test/projects) to 0.11.0-SNAPSHOT and grails 2.3.7.

The geb example now uses the latest versions of geb and webdriver. There is also a small code change in `ListPage`. The `url` should be `book/index` instead of `book/list`.

To use fork mode you will need at least grails 2.3.8.

Hope that helps :)